# How To Override EditorForModel() in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When we use **EditorForModel**() in mvc , it created a form without a submit button .

I want override this html helper to add submit button .

How can I do this?

I searched in site but I dont find any useful result.

Comment: Have you tried creating an `EditorTemplate` for the type? What about [`EditorForModel(this HtmlHelper html, string templateName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430912(v=vs.118).aspx)? Alternatively, what about `EditorFor(_ => Model, "ViewName")`?

Comment: @ta.speot. is Should I use **EditorTemplate**?

Comment: @osmanRahimi yeah, you should use EditorTemplate